# Update a webpage depending on user inputs

Tags: java, javascript, html, button, controls

I have a very simple question that I'm looking for a hello-world type tutorial on:

My goal is alter one part of a webpage depending on external factors. So, in this example to have a block of text in the website that says "Apple". If the "Banana" button is clicked, that text now says "Banana" and if the "Pear" button is pressed it would then say "Pear".

I'd prefer to do this using javascript if possible. I'd appreciate any links to preexisting templates if they exist.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that could easily be done like:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WXgRP/

HTML:

```
<p id='changeme'>Blah</p>
<a href='#'>Banana</a>
<a href='#'>Apples</a>
```

JS:

```
el = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
[].forEach.call(el, function(ele, index, arr) {
    ele.onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById('changeme').innerHTML = ele.innerHTML;   
    }
});
```

So what this does, is el gets all elements in the page by Tag name, you can modify this as you please to get my classname, attribute, id

`[].forEach.call` gives the `forEach` the `this` value of the NodeList so on each loop you can access their properties, each loop sets the `a` link to set the `innerHTML` of an element to the text you gave to the a link.

Comment: Done :) I'm new to SO and still learning how things are done here.

Answer (score 0):

This question could be resolved with a simple web search, but I will post an answer since SO tends to rank highly in results.

Here is some HTML:

```
<label><input type="radio" value="Apple" name="fruit"/>Apple</label>
<label><input type="radio" value="Banana" name="fruit"/>Banana</label>
<label><input type="radio" value="Pear" name="fruit"/>Pear</label>
<h1 id="selection"></h1>
```

Here is the JavaScript (using jQuery):

```
$('input').bind('click', function () {
    $('#selection').html(this.value);
});
```

Note that I would not use jQuery if this is the only thing you need to do, but if there are a lot of interactive aspects to your website, then jQuery will make your life much easier.

The JavaScript does the following:

Assign an event handler to all input elements so that a function gets called when they are clicked.

The input calls the function when clicked, so `this` refers to the input, whose value contains the name of the fruit.

`$('#selection')` means the DOM element whose id attribute is "selection."  This is the heading `h1` in our case.

The `.html` method, when passed an argument, will assign the argument (`this.value`) to the inner HTML of the heading element.